# Portable make rule without wildcard

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a portable makefile using suffixes for a build target instead of the '%' wildcard syntax implemented by GNU make.  Here's my Makefile:

```
SUFFIXES = .xml.in .xml
all: test.xml
.xml.in.xml:
    echo "Hello"
```

Running `make` gives me "No rule to make target `test.xml'".  However if I use the wildcard:

```
all: test.xml
%.xml: %.xml.in
    echo "Hello"
```

it works.  I assume I'm having issues because one of my extensions has a period in it, is there a workaround for this?

Comment: `SUFFIXES = .xml.in .xml` -> `.SUFFIXES: .xml.in .xml`. Either way unless you need to support ancient versions of make there's no reason to use suffix rules instead of pattern rules.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "portable"?